# Getting XPath from XmlSchemaElement

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

I am doing some parsing and iterating over XML (specifically XSD) elements (XmlSchemaElement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaelement?view=netcore-3.1) using C# and .NET. While iterating over nodes, I want to fetch their Xpaths but don't know how to do that. I see there is XmlSchemaXPath class available, but don't know is it possible to use it to get Xpath from XmlSchemaElement.
For now I am making Xpath by concatenating nodes into one string like "/node1/node1child1/node987...", while iterating over them, but this obviously isn't good way to do it.

Comment: It is not clear what you consider "the" XPath for an element. There is not a single XPath expression selecting a particular node. I don't think XmlSchemaXPath is for generating XPath expressions, it is just the representation of the `xs:selector` element in the W3C schema language (used with `xs:key` or `xs:unique`). XPath 3.1 has a `path` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-path that returns a path expression but its format is not necessarily easy for human consumption as it ensures it works without namespace declarations using the `Q{uri}foo` notation.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thank you for reply. I am working on XSD schemas for EDI and iDoc message formats specifically. So I wanna get human consumable Xpaths for every XML element like following: 
/ns0:INVOIC96A/S_UNB/D_0026 (this is example for EDI segment);
/ORDERS05/IDOC/EDI_DC40/@SEGMENT  (this is example for node attribute from iDoc).